# Using Google sheets arrays like in Microsoft Excel (ANDING two arrays)

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Hello I would like to combine two arrays in google in such a way:

={TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}

Where the result should equal: {FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}

In excel that formula listed above works. In google I simply get 0 as the result. What should I enter in google to get the result like I do in excel?

Example in excel I am trying to achieve [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpLI5.png)

Example in Google Sheets: [Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FhzT.png)

Tried:
={TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}

Expected:
{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}

Comment: Nest this on `=INDEX(....)` and see if that solved it. In excel you may have access to dynamic arrays whereas implicit intersection is still a thing in GS

Comment: Have you tried simply using `ARRAYFORMULA`? For example, `=ARRAYFORMULA({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE})`. Or, if you insist on an array of Booleans: `=ARRAYFORMULA({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}=1)`

Comment: @JosWoolley can you make this comment an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE})
```

and if you want a boolean back do:

```
=INDEX(TRUE=({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using `ARRAYFORMULA`? For example,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE})
```

Or, if you insist on an array of Booleans:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}*{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}=1)
```